# Non-blocking socket for server

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing, nonblocking

I've checked few similar threads on stackoverflow.com and I think I might need to open non-blocking socket for my server script. Since, I'm not sure that this is the solution question title might be wrong. Let me explain what is my problem.

Server app waits for connection and once client connects it will ask for server ID, after that client will ask for server configuration and than client will send command to server to start measurement transmission. Here's simplified version of my code:

```
def conn_handler(self, connection, address):
    self.logger.info("[%d] - Connection from %s:%d", 10, address[0], address[1])

    sending_measurements_enabled = False
    try:
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(2048)

            if data:
                command = get_command_from_data(data)
            else:
                command = None

            if command == 'start':
                sending_measurements_enabled = True
            elif command == 'stop':
                break
            elif command == 'id':
                connection.sendall(self.id)
            elif command == 'cfg':
                connection.sendall(self.cfg)

            if sending_measurements_enabled:
                connection.sendall(measurement)

    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
    finally:
        connection.close()
        print("Connection closed")
```

And here is client script:

```
try:

    sock.sendall(get_id_command)    

    data = sock.recv(2048) # Do I need to wait for response?
    print(data)

    sock.sendall(get_conf_command)

    data = sock.recv(2048)
    print(data)

    sock.sendall(start_sending_measurements)
    data = sock.recv(2048)
    print(data)

    while True:
        sock.sendall(bytes('I do not want this', 'utf-8')) # I would like to keep receiving measurements without this
        data = sock.recv(2048)
        print(data)

finally:
    print('Closing socket...')
    sock.close()
```

And here is my problem:

When I run client and send command to get ID server will return ID message, then client will send command to get configuration and server will return configuration message but when I send `start` command server will send only one measurement and than I guess `connection.recv(2048)` will block execution until server gets another command. So, I added that line inside `while True:` loop in client script which will keep sending (unnecessary, invalid) commands and server will keep sending measurements.

How to solve this without sending commands all the time from client. I want to be able to send only one command `start` and server will keep sending measurements, and stop only when client sends `stop` command.
Also, if server receives `id` or `cfg` command while sending measurements it will first send `id` or `cfg` and than keep sending measurements.

Comment: The `else` to `if data:` should act like command 'stop' because an empty `data` at that point means the other side has closed the connection and therefore doesn't send anything anymore.

Comment: Instead of a non-blocking socket you may also use a thread for sending measurements.

Comment: @BlackJack Client sends empty package only when it's trying to terminate connection?  If Client didn't send anything (in code below) code inside `if readable:` block will never get executed and if Client sends empty package that means connection should be closed?

Comment: It's not an ”empty” packet, it's the condition that the client closed the connection that leads to `recv()` returning zero bytes. You can't actually send nothing in a stream by doing `sendall('')` on one end. That call has no effect. It certainly doesn't lead to a `recv()` on the other end to return with an empty string. Also TCP doesn't know about packets. It's a data stream. If you want to transmit packets _you_ have to make sure to isolate them from the stream. There is no guaranteed relation between sending _n_ bytes in one call and the other end receiving _n_ bytes with one call!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the server loop call `select.select([connection], [connection], [connection])` ([select](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) module provides more facilities, so pick your favorite). If the socket is readable, read command and react on it. If the socket is writable (and there was a request for data), send measurements.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs this:

```
def conn_handler(self, connection, address):
    self.logger.info("[%d] - Connection from %s:%d", 10, address[0], address[1])

    sending_measurements_enabled = False
    try:
        while True:

            command = None
            readable, writable, exceptional = select([connection], [], [], 0)

            if readable:
               data = connection.recv(2048)

               if data:
                   command = get_command_from_data(data)
                   print("Received command %s", command)


            if command == 'start':
                sending_measurements_enabled = True
            elif command == 'stop':
                break
            elif command == 'id':
                connection.sendall(self.id)
            elif command == 'cfg':
                connection.sendall(self.cfg)

            if sending_measurements_enabled:
                connection.sendall(measurement)

    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
    finally:
        connection.close()
        print("Connection closed")
```

Comment: What happens if the `recv()` call did read just part of a command? This doesn't look very robust.

Comment: @BlackJack right now I have very short commands and everything works OK. But I will have to refactor this, not sure how since I don't have delimiter in command. I guess I will have to loop `connection.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)` until I get valid command?

Comment: Or you add a delimiter.  Or use fixed size.  Or prefix length information with fixed size.